# How to preserve punctuation marks in Scikit-Learn text CountVectorizer or TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, punctuation, countvectorizer

Is there any way for me to preserve punctuation marks of !, ?, " and ' from my text documents using text `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer` parameters in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should customize the `token_pattern` parameter when you instantiate the vectorizer. For example:

```
vent = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'")
```

Comment: Thank you @elyase for fast reply. The escape |!|\?|\"|\' did work. I've tried from parameter '(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'' but it didin't work, my poor knowledge. So why is there must r" '" anyway?. Thanks dude...

Comment: glad to help! Regarding the raw string (r'string') take a look at the 2nd paragraph [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html).