# Vectorize string including punctuation and special characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas, scikit-learn, vectorization

I need to vectorize different sets of tokenized strings including punctuation and special characters like ?,!,#,/,➧,❤,➽ or ✓ - I am using pandas and scikit-learn for that task but the CountVectorize function only vectorize words and ignoring additional characters. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254134/how-to-preserve-punctuation-marks-in-scikit-learn-text-countvectorizer-or-tfidfv) but i have no list of the additional characters and need all of them. Here is my code for that task:

```
def vectorize (dataframe,column_supplement):
     v = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word", encoding='utf-8', max_features = 5000)
     x = v.fit_transform(dataframe['string_tokenized'])
     df_result = pd.DataFrame(x.todense(), columns=v.get_feature_names())
     instances = df_result.values.tolist()
     header = list(df_result)
     for i in range(len(header)):
     header[i] = column_supplement+header[i]
     df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(instances, columns=header)
     return df
```

Thanks for help and ideas!

PS token_pattern (default u'(?u)\b\w\w+\b') regular expression identifying tokens–by default words that consist of a single character (e.g., ‘a’, ‘2’) are ignored, setting token_pattern to '(?u)\b\w+\b' will include these tokens

Answer (score 0):

You might find the accepted answer provided by @Venkatachalam in this stackoverflow question helpful. [Sk Learn CountVectorizer: keeping emojis as words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57333183/sk-learn-countvectorizer-keeping-emojis-as-words)

By using `token_pattern=r'[^\s+]'` we set the `token_pattern` to be **any character except one or more whitespaces.**

As a result the following items will be treated as tokens:

- punctuation sequences like `!#$` or even single punctuation marks like `*` or `.`
- special characters like emojis .
- single character letters eg `a`,`C`

Comment: I think the token_pattern should change to `r[^\s]+`. Otherwise, the pattern only matches a single character.