# Sk Learn CountVectorizer: keeping emojis as words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

I am using Sk Learn `CountVectorizer` on strings but `CountVectorizer` discards all the emojis in the text.

For instance,  `Welcome` should give us: `["\xf0\x9f\x91\x8b", "welcome"]`

However, when running:

```py
vect = CountVectorizer()
test.fit_transform([' Welcome'])
```

I only get: `["welcome"]`

This has to do with the `token_pattern` which does not count the encoded emoji as a word, but is there a custom `token_pattern` to deal with emojis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you are right! `token_pattern` has to be changed. Instead of just alpha-numeric characters, we can make it as **any character other than white space**.

Try this!

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
s= [' Welcome', ' Welcome']

v = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=r'[^\s]+')
v.fit(s)
v.get_feature_names()

# ['welcome', '']
```

Answer (score 3):

Also there is a [couple](https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot) of [packages](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) out there that can transform emojis/emoticons into words directly e.g.

```
import emot
>>> text = "I love python  :-)"
>>> emot.emoji(text)
[{'value': '', 'mean': ':man:', 'location': [14, 14], 'flag': True}]

>> import emoji
>> print(emoji.demojize('Python is '))
Python is :thumbs_up:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the parameters `CountVectorizer(analyzer = 'char', binary = True)`

The docs say that: "token_pattern: Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'" see https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html.

Also see this notebook: https://www.kaggle.com/kmader/toxic-emojis