# how to consider 'punctuation ' in CountVectorizer?

Tags: nlp, countvectorizer

I am using CountVectorizer of Sklearn to convert my strings into a vector. However, CountVectorizer by default select tokens of 2 of more characters and also ignore the punctuation and considered them as a separator. I want to consider even one character as a token and also include punctuation. For example:

```
aaa 1 2.75 zzz
aaa 2 3.75 www
```

I want a matrix of

```
1 1 1 0 1 1 0 
1 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this goal?

Comment: I think that nice suggestions is here vent = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'")
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254134/how-to-preserve-punctuation-marks-in-scikit-learn-text-countvectorizer-or-tfidfv

Comment: This is quite different from what I am looking for. I want to preserve '.' as part of token but the link provided reg expression that considers '.' as a separate word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom tokenizer as in this example:

```py
import re

new_docs=["aaa 1 2.75 zzz","aaa 2 3.75 www"]

def my_tokenizer(text):
    return re.split("\\s+",text)


cv = CountVectorizer(new_docs,tokenizer=my_tokenizer)
count_vector=cv.fit_transform(new_docs)
print(cv.vocabulary_)
```

Example output:

```
{'aaa': 4, '1': 0, '2.75': 2, 'zzz': 6, '2': 1, '3.75': 3, 'www': 5}
```

See more [CountVectorizer usage examples here](https://kavita-ganesan.com/how-to-use-countvectorizer/#Custom-Tokenization).