# Sklearn CountVectorizer token_pattern that allows strings with any characters

Tags: python, regex, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I want to write a `token_pattern=` for `CountVectorizer` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)) that allows any strings to be passed in as tokens.

The default excludes a lot including strings with hyphens...

The closest I have is:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_patten=r"(?u)\b\w\w+\b|!|\?|\"|\'")
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254134/how-to-preserve-punctuation-marks-in-scikit-learn-text-countvectorizer-or-tfidfv).

But my skill in regex is lacking so I've been unable to successfully customize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

This allows any strings.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r'.*')
```